# ¿Es correcto decir: "Tu vestido es muy guapo."?

Tags: adjetivos

Mi novia dice que [debería decir](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vestido+muy+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=es-2019&smoothing=10), *Tu vestido es muy bonito.*, diciendo que cosas como
vestido no los describimos como [guapos](https://dle.rae.es/guapo?m=form)? ¿Es correcto decir, *Tu vestido es muy guapo.*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En principio te diría que tu novia tiene razón, pero si te fijas [en este otro NGrama](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=est%C3%A1%20guapo&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=es-2019&smoothing=10) podrás constatar que el uso de la expresión **está guapo** ha crecido desde el año 2000.

[image: NGram esta guapo]

Eso se debe a que ha pasado a ser parte de la jerga moderna para indicar aprecio por algo, que algo está bien o muy bien.

Aquí [tienes un ejemplo](https://www.timeout.es/madrid/es/noticias/20-palabras-y-expresiones-que-todo-madrilenyo-deberia-conocer-111020) de su uso

> Su uso es bien sencillo: mazo sustituye al muy o al mucho, según
> convenga. Y así, algo bueno no **está bien**, sino mazo **guapo**

Siento que esté mezclado con otra palabra de jerga madrileña como mazo. Aquí en Málaga (Andalucía, España) decimos que algo (incluyendo un vestido):

> Está tó **guapo**, canío

Puedes sustituir canío [canijo] por compare [compadre], loco o bro [del inglés bro y que significa lo mismo en este contexto y que es sinónimo de los otros apelativos que listo]

Así que dependiendo de con quien estés hablando, debes escoger cómo quieres decirlo. Menores de 40 años en un entorno distendido [está guapo]; mayores, tu novia, un entorno formal o un país hispanohablante distinto de España [es bonito]. Se pueden usar los verbos **ser** y estar indistintamente en este caso, aunque es más común usar **estar**.

Un ejemplo para @Ananias usando el verbo ser
[image: Coches muy guapos]

Comment: @Ananias Como indico al final, se usa también el verbo "ser" y he especificado en qué contexto puede emplear la expresión. Nos guste o no, está ahí en las calles.

Comment: @Ananias Ya tienes tu referencia, ¿contento?

Comment: @Ananias La respuesta estaba totalmente relacionada y justificada antes. El +1 no se ha reflejado pero gracias.